# Solving SDE system in Ito form

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, stochastic-calculus

Can mathematica solve a linear SDE system in Ito form, for example

$$ \begin{equation}
  \begin{bmatrix}
   dx_1 \\
   dx_2 \\
   dx_3 \\
   dx_4
  \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
   x_1 & ix_2 & -ix_3 & x_3 \\
   ix_2 & ix_2 & -ix_4 & x_1 \\
   ix_2 & -ix_1 & ix_3 & x_1 \\
   ix_4 & -ix_4 & ix_2 & x_3
  \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
   dW_{1}(z) \\
   dW_{2}(z) \\
   dW_{3}(z) \\
   dW_{4}(z) 
  \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}
   x_1 \\
   x_2 \\
   x_3 \\
   x_4
  \end{bmatrix}dz.
 \end{equation}
$$

where $x_{1,2,3,4}(z),$ and the independent Brownian motions $dW(z)_{1,2,3,4}$? I have initial conditions $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)_{z=0} = (1,0,0,1).$ I tried:

```
proc = ItoProcess[{\[DifferentialD]kai1[z] == 
    I*kai1[z] \[DifferentialD]w1[z] + 
     I*kai1 [z] \[DifferentialD]w2[z] - 
     I*kai3[z] \[DifferentialD]w3[z] + kai3[z] \[DifferentialD]w4[z] +
      kai1[z] \[DifferentialD]z,
   \[DifferentialD]kai2[z] == 
    I*kai2[z] \[DifferentialD]w1[z] + 
     I*kai2[z] \[DifferentialD]w2[z] - 
     I*kai4[z] \[DifferentialD]w3[z] + kai4[z] \[DifferentialD]w4[z] +
      kai2[z] \[DifferentialD]z,
   \[DifferentialD]kai3[z] == 
    I*kai1[z] \[DifferentialD]w1[z] - 
     I*kai3[z] \[DifferentialD]w2[z] + 
     I*kai1[z] \[DifferentialD]w3[z] + kai1[z] \[DifferentialD]w4[z] +
      kai3[z] \[DifferentialD]z,
   \[DifferentialD]kai4[z] == 
    I*kai4[z] \[DifferentialD]w1[z] + 
     I*kai1[z] \[DifferentialD]w2[z] - 
     I*kai3[z] \[DifferentialD]w3[z] + kai3[z] \[DifferentialD]w4[z] +
      kai1[z] \[DifferentialD]z}, {kai1[z], kai2[z], kai3[z], 
   kai4[z]}, {{kai1, kai2, kai3, kai4}, {1, 0, 0, 1}}, z, 
  w1 \[Distributed] WienerProcess[], 
  w2 \[Distributed] WienerProcess[], 
  w3 \[Distributed] WienerProcess[], 
  w4 \[Distributed] WienerProcess[]]
```

where I have changed slightly the equations, it's not so important for this question. How do I then plot these processes?

Comment: Yes. Make sure to read the documentations of `ItoProcess`, `WienerProcess`, and `RandomFunction`.

Comment: Can you look at my updated question? I have improved it.

Comment: Run `RandomFunction` on the `ItoProcess` object and plot the resulting `TemporalData` object with, eg., `ListLinePlot`.

Comment: I tried that, but I get an error "The specification...proc...is not a random process recognised by the system"

Comment: I think the problem comes from defining multiple Brownian motions. Do you have any ideas to help me? Thank you.

Comment: Yeah. Now that I tried it a bit, I come to the conclusion that the `ItoProcess` documentation page is the worst one I have ever read. Super confusing: It suggests that you can use simple vectorial notation but when it comes to the Brownian motion, you see that `WienerProcess` does not accept a drift vector and covariance matrix...

Comment: So what you're saying is...no?

Comment: No, I am sure that one _can_ do it, but at the moment I just do not have the time to figure out how.

Comment: i have solved it. You just need to put brackets around the Weiner processes.

Comment: D'oh........ -.-

Comment: Stupid question, but I have posted again. How to extract individual solution paths from the solution?

Comment: Erm. Must be doable with `data[string]` where `data` is the resulting `TemporalData` object and `string` is one one of `data["Properties"]`. One of these propertoes should contain an array of size $n \times 4$, where $n$ is the number of time steps. Then `data[string][[All, i]]` should give you the $i$-component at all times. You have to look around a bit. Sorry, I cannot be more precise at the moment.